# How to keep actionbar fixed across all activities?

Tags: android-actionbar, android

In the Facebook app v2.3, when you navigate from one activity(or frgament?) to another, the actionbar stays fixed across all activities(or fragments?). For example, If you navigate from you news feed to someone's profile page, then the action bar stays constant, and the page below is refreshed. So my question is, is it possible to have this behavior using only activities? Or should i just have one main activity, and fragments for all sub activities?

Comment: I believe it's one primary activity and then fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One activity and as many fragments as you need.

the moment you call `startActivity(intent);` the framework will roll the activity transition animation with all its contents (including the action bar)

Comment: I disabled animations for activity transitions in my app, and its working perfect. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: it's another way of doing it that I didn't think of. But just keep in mind that it means the ActionBar is still being replaced, it simply doesn't have an animation. So it might not look as perfect on slower/older devices.

Comment: So do you suggest having different fragments instead of activities? What would be a better approach?

Comment: I already got very used as developer to use fragment for everything, so my opinion is VERY biased to it. But you can try get some devices or use emulator to test how it would behave.

Answer (score 2):

You can have this behaviour using only Activities. These are the methods you need in each Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.button_1:
            handleButton1();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.button_2:
            handleButton2();
            return true;
           ...
        default:
           ...
    }
}
```

Also, you can access action bar object, in your onCreate, and customize it the way you want. For example, enabling home button etc:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
```

But, if you have many activities, you probably don't want to do this in each of them. Instead, you can have this code in a Super-class activity, and then have other activities extend it. This is the preferred way -  you do it in one place only.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I want to keep the action bar fixed during transition to another activty. Using the above approach refreshes the entire activity, I do not want the action bar to refresh